# JQuery append option in select element not working when server have time delay

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I am making a web site with Flask and I hope I can get all the product list from server, and append to options in select element.

This is my JS code

```
$('#addModalPopup').click(() => {
    $.get('/getProductInfos', function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            $("#productInfo").append($("<option></option>")
                             .text(data[i].PRODUCT_INFOS));
        }
    })
})
```

And this is my python code

```
@purchasing_blueprint.route('/getProductInfos', methods=['GET'])
def get_products():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        time.sleep(2)
        query_str = get_product_infos_query_string()
        db = get_db()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        product_infos = cursor.execute(query_str)
        colname = [ d[0] for d in product_infos.description ]
        product_infos_list = [ dict(zip(colname, r)) for r in product_infos.fetchall()]
        return jsonify(product_infos_list)
```

I put time.sleep() in server side to simulate the delay of request to DataBase

But I realized that the option will not be append if time.sleep() is exists in server side, but if I comment the sleep function, append goes will, is there any solution or reason ?

Cause if there are a big delay in the future, I think the scenario will be like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#addModalPopup').click(() => {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                 url: '/getProductInfos',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 traditional: true,
                
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {

                     for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                      $("#productInfo").append($("<option></option>")
                         .text(result[i].PRODUCT_INFOS));
                      }
                }
            });
        });
```

use this code js

Comment: Send with type=Post Maybe It may be true

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why the `sleep` delay broke the request... But to simulate a delay on the response, you can do it on client-side with a setTimeout, after the response is received.

```
$('#addModalPopup').click(() => {
  $.get('/getProductInfos', function(data){
    setTimeout(function(){
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        $("#productInfo").append($("<option></option>")
                         .text(data[i].PRODUCT_INFOS));
      }
    },2000);
  })
})
```

Comment: It did not brake the request , It just can't append the option when the callback occur